# How to crop a tiff image in asp.net

Tags: c#

I was looking for a routine by which I can crop tiff image and I got it but it gives many error. Here is the routine:

```
Bitmap comments = null;
string input = "somepath";
// Open a Stream and decode a TIFF image
using (Stream imageStreamSource = new FileStream(input, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
TiffBitmapDecoder decoder = new TiffBitmapDecoder(imageStreamSource, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);

BitmapSource bitmapSource = decoder.Frames[0];
using (Bitmap b = BitmapFromSource(bitmapSource))
{
Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle(169, 1092, 567, 200);
comments = new Bitmap(cropRect.Width, cropRect.Height);

//first cropping
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(comments))
{
g.DrawImage(b, new Rectangle(0, 0, comments.Width, comments.Height),
cropRect,
GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
}
}
```

When I try to compile it, I get an error. I tried adding references to many assemblies searching google but couldn't resolve it. I got this code from this url:

```
http://snipplr.com/view/63053/
```

I am looking for advice.

Comment: It sure helps adding the error you get....

Comment: Also, please provide more info on the TIFF image itself (color, multiframe, etc.). GDI+/.NET out of the box have trouble with certain kinds of TIFF files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TiffBitmapDecoder` class is from `Presentation.Core` in another words it is from WPF.

BitmapFromSource isn't method of any .net framework class. You can convert BitmapSource to Bitmap using this code.

```
private Bitmap BitmapFromSource(BitmapSource bitmapsource)
 {
     Bitmap bitmap;
     using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
     {
       BitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
       encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapsource));
       encoder.Save(outStream);
       bitmap = new Bitmap(outStream);
     }
     return bitmap;
 }
```